# Extract zip-files from external server to own server

Tags: php, zip

I wrote the following function:

```
private function downloadFile($url) {
    // since this is a zip-file, we need to unzip it
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $res = $zip->open($url);
    if ($res == true) {
        $oModule = oxNew("oxModule");
        $sModuleDir = $oModule->getModulePath("trosofortueberweisung");
        $sShopDir = $this->getConfig()->getConfigParam('sShopDir');
        $sCopyPath = $sShopDir . "modules/" . $sModuleDir;
        $zip->extractTo($sCopyPath);
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

My **$url** = `example.org/myfile.zip` (an external server). The Script however runs on another server. What I want to do is an automatic update-function.

I want to get the zip-file from a hosted server, open it and extract the files to a specific location. However, I get the following error:

> Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo() [ziparchive.extractto]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in ...

as well as

> Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in ...

Ideas why that is? $res is obv. true since it arrives in the statement :/

**Update 1**

I changed the if-statement to `===` and it when i `var_dump($res)` it shows **int(11)** which refers to:

> Can't open file

(from [here](http://php.net/manual/de/ziparchive.open.php))